# Swift 3: UIPickerView inside ScrollView

Tags: swift3, uiscrollview, uipickerview

I have a `UIPickerView` embedded inside a `UIScrollView`, using Swift 3. The `UIScrollView` is embedded inside a `UIView` and scrolls vertically fine. However I also have a UIPickerview embedded inside the `UIScrollView`. The `UIPickerView` does not scroll when clicking on it in iphone (It works fine in the simulator).

Have tried adding : `scrollView.delaysContentTouches = false` and `scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = false;` this stops the ScrollView from scrolling completely.

Answer (score -1):

```
pickerView.exclusiveTouch = true
scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = false
```